# Want a plugin which can be used to show a map(not actual map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a requirment where I want to create a map of a particular field and place things like wastebin,light pole. It should be able to zoom and pan. I tried using scattered map but the image behind is not zooming. Is there a way

My Data will be in json

```
{
  {X=20
   Y=30
   Object= Bin
  },
 {X=120
  Y=230
  Object= Bin
 },
     Picture="Zombiefield.png",
    Zoomlevel=10
   }
```

LIke the google map functionality but with the simple high resolution picture of a field.

I am looking for a solution or a plugin in jquery,javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or a link with an article how it can be done will be helpful so that i can learn too

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project requirement and I had used this plugin. **[mindprojects/jqzoom](https://github.com/mindprojects/jqzoom)**

What it does is that you can show a normal image and once someone hovers over it with a cursor, a new popup div shows the magnified image. Standard eg:-

```
$('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
    zoomType: 'standard',
    lens:true,
    preloadImages: false,
    alwaysOn:false
  });
```

How it looks:-

[image: Image zoom on hover jquery plugin, mouse pointer hover javascript plugin, Enlarge Image on hover javascript]

Comment: Nice. But my requirement is just like google map. Once they zoom in, lets say using Scroll. It should stay like that. So at first the system will show only buildings icons. Once they scoll in it shows the smaller icons like lamp post, The scroll level is static. 1-15. 1 15 being closest.